# Omitting a "NOT NULL" value during an INSERT defaults it to 0. Why?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table structure:

[image]

`badge_id` and `interface_id` are **primary keys**.

When I attempt an **INSERT** operation specifying only the `badge_id`, I expected it to fail, but instead `interface_id` **defaults to 0**.

[image]

I'm running the following versions:

[image]

Could somebody explain why it defaults to zero? Shouldn't this fail?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your insert statement output, there was one warning. Did you checked that? It might explain something.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't really notice. I just repeated the statements with the "show warning" flags, and received "Warning (Code 1364): Field 'interface_id' doesn't have a default value"! A step in the right direction, but why the default to zero then instead of an error?

Comment: Could you please use text instead of images for your code? StackOverflow (SO) is designed to be searchable, and using images defeats that purpose.

Comment: I used images to make it clearer, the text formatting always seems more difficult to read/scan. But you are right, I'll do so in the future.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of MySQL...

Comment: If you wrap the text from the console in to `<pre>` tags, it looks pretty good.

Comment: What SQL mode are you running in?  I'm guessing it's not `strict`.

Comment: Formatted text is definitely easier to read than shonky screen prints of white text on black console output.

Comment: It's not a duplicate. This question asks for the reason of an unexpected behavior. The question you linked to asks for ways to prevent an expected behavior.

Comment: But your linked question is useful to me, so thanks, even if that wasn't your intention. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html

> As of MySQL 5.0.2, if a column definition includes no explicit DEFAULT value, MySQL determines the default value as follows:
>
> If the column can take NULL as a value, the column is defined with an explicit DEFAULT NULL clause. This is the same as before 5.0.2.
>
> If the column cannot take NULL as the value, MySQL defines the column with no explicit DEFAULT clause. For data entry, if an INSERT or REPLACE statement includes no value for
>   the column, MySQL handles the column according to the SQL mode in effect at the time:
>
> If strict SQL mode is not enabled, MySQL sets the column to the implicit default value for the column data type.

Comment: This is exactly the page I linked to in my answer.

Comment: @Jocelyn - but you failed to highlight the important part about strict SQL mode...

Comment: Woops, did not see that another answer was written while I was formatting mine. My bad.

Comment: Seems like not running strict mode is the reason.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is in the documentation for [CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html):

> If a column definition includes no explicit DEFAULT value, MySQL
>   determines the default value as described in Section 11.5, “Data Type
>   Default Values”.

More information is available in [Data type default values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/data-type-defaults.html):

> Implicit defaults are defined as follows:  For numeric types, the
>   default is 0, with the exception that for integer or floating-point
>   types declared with the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute, the default is the
>   next value in the sequence.